# Ways of creating reusable header with react

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router

I am new in react and I am searching the best way for creating a reusable header.
The goals is to reuse a header component in multiple apps by passing somes properties such as:
- Main Title
- Logo
- String List of menus and route paths for render multiple buttons menus for the navigation
- And a boolean for a last button menus for administration

Finally the signature exemple of the component would be something like:
`<Header title="title" menus_json=[{'title':'tab1', 'route_path'='/tab1'},...] logo_path=[] admin=False />`

How can we achieve that ? Any suggestion, documentation for that ?

Comment: Get dirty with props in react,then you would be able to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a **Header** component and pass dynamically to every component where needed by values.

Header.js

```
function Header({title,menus_json,logo_path,admin}){
return (
   <header>
    // use your title,menus_json,logo_path,admin
   </header>
 )
}
```

Use like this in needed components - example

**Component1.js**

```
function Component1(){
    return (
       <div>
        <Header title="title" logo_path=[] admin=False
         menus_json=[{'title':'tab1', 'route_path'='/tab1'}] />
        <div>...</div>
       </div>
      )
    }
```

**Component2.js** with different values `title`,`menus_json`...etc.

```
function Component2(){
        return (
           <div>
            <Header title="title2" logo_path=[] admin=False
             menus_json=[{'title':'tab2', 'route_path'='/tab2'}] />
            <div>...</div>
           </div>
          )
        }
```